# How to get video file stream from embed url in c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, httpclient, embed

I tried this below code but video is not playing.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var data = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/iRFE-sKOp4I"));
var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("myfile.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var targetStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await targetStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
await targetStream.FlushAsync();
targetStream.Dispose();
```

Any one please help me to how to save download..thankyou

Comment: If you want to download the video, see this : https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/

Comment: @x... With out using Youtubedownloder is it possible to download through HttpClient or any other Clients..

Comment: See the source code, he use also HttpClient inside his source code. The process is: first get the list of all available videos, then download one of the video from the list.

Comment: But with that same code i can't to download different website videos..

Comment: No, only youtube. Actually, youtube is not allowing you to download video. That is forbidden.

Comment: Actually I want to download https://openload.co/embed/EHmDelqNx94 video is there any possibility..

Comment: You can download that url, its HTML and you must find the link of video inside that HTML. I dont know where, because its encrypted.

Comment: You should find video uri and download video by uri (not player uri). You can try to parse html and get it. After having **video** uri you can use `HttpClient` or `BackgroundDownloader` for download source.

Comment: @NikitaBondarenko thanks for your replay, the video url appears after click on play button, is there any way to handle click event by httpclient or any other clients..

Comment: Where is uri appears? In the html?

Comment: After playing the video search for video tag, in inspect element of page.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't download video without video link :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @x..., If you want to download video from Youtube, you need to install the [YoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/).

> But with that same code i can't to download different website videos.

I tested your code with a video download uri "http://video.ch9.ms/ch9/9b56/4f2d0b4d-ea37-4525-8833-128ad6e69b56/uwp01SeriesIntro.mp4", it works fine.

> Actually I want to download openload.co/embed/EHmDelqNx94 video is there any possibility..

I just took a look at this video, I find this a web named openload, and this web service share free without limits, but you need to use the [develop Api](https://openload.co/api) of it. For downloading, you can refer to the download [APIs here](https://openload.co/api#download-getlink).

> the video url appears after click on play button, is there any way to handle click event by httpclient or any other clients

From the official document of this web, I found this:

> get a download link by using download ticket.

You can refer to [Download Link](https://openload.co/api#download-getlink).

**Update:**

> i tried openload api, but when get download link it showing captcha error, can you please help me for this

I just reproduced your problem, this is because your source for download is not a  public source, it needed authentication. When you get the `Download Ticket` for download, although the Api said `API-Login` and `API-Key` are not required, you need to use the full path `https://api.openload.co/1/file/dlticket?file={file}&login={login}&key={key}` to get an authenticated ticket, then you can use this ticket to get the download URL.

Comment: Hello  Grace Feng thank you for your valuable information, i tried openload api, but when get download link it showing captcha error, can you please help me for this..

Comment: @DeviPrasad, I just updated my answer, please have a check. ;)

Comment: How can i get apilogin and key for authenticating